# HTML5 - view excel file

Tags: html

We would like to display excel file which consist of graphs onto our HTML5 web page.

I tried couple of approach but haven't got exact solution-

1. If I used iframe then source excel file opens as an attachment and dialog box appears. which I dont want.
2. If I convert excel file into mht and then open using iframe. This only works with IE and not mozilla or chrome.

Can anyone please suggest how to view entire excel workbook on my HTML5 page?

Note: I do not want to use google docs in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: http://www.labnol.org/software/embed-tables-spreadsheet-data-in-websites/7435/

It has multiples ways of embedding spreadsheets into html pages

Comment: Looking to embed excel with graphs.